# VBA - Read text file, search for a next row matching current row, and merge

Tags: vba, ms-access

I will try provide as much details so my apologies for the long question.

I am trying to loop twice through a text file, merge data from two rows, and write it to a table in the Access database (accdb) where this VBA resides.

I apologize upfront, I did only simple VBA processing and I don't know how to sort, search and merge.  I've searched this forum but couldn't identify code sample that will help.

This is a text file with millions of rows.  Each row contains lots of information about an item.

In each row:

```
Columns 1-8: Item ID.
Column 20-21: Action Code
Columns 31-38: effective date.
```

What I need to do is (I am simplifying it):
Loop through the file and find all items where action code = X5.

When I find an action of "X5", I need to find the next action for this particular item and see what action was it.

Than write one row to the database with Item ID, Effective date Row1, action code Row1 (will be X5), effective date Row2, action code Row2.

I need some other data for this item, but the core are the above five fields.

Example:

```
ItemID, Effective Date, Action Code
1111, 20010312, A3
1111, 20070428, X5
1111, 20070629, Z2
1111, 20090312, Z3
2222, 20070428, M2
2222, 20070629, Z6
2222, 20090312, X5
3333, 20070428, X4
3333, 20070629, L3
```

In this example I will write to the database only one row:

```
1111, 20070428, X5, 20070629, Z2
```

For 2222 although there is an X5 action there is no other action after that.

I am not sure the file is sorted so I might need to read it into two record sets (or any other ideas you might have) and sort it.

I appreciate any sample of code you can provide. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for trouble with your suggested approach, i.e. to loop through the text data twice, with sorting.  This would involve a lot of code, which would be unnecessary given Access' native capabilities.

You would be better off importing your data into a raw-data/temp table (use Access' data import wizard, save the import definition, then use `DoCmd.TransferText` in your code to pull the data into your table).

From there, you can `OpenRecordset` your raw data as a single DAO Recordset sorted as required, and open your destination recordset.  Loop through the data, get your first-record values, `MoveNext` and get the second-record values where appropriate, then `AddNew` to your destination database, assign the values found, and `Update`.

Given that your source data has millions of rows, you might then want to delete the raw/temp data or even delete the whole raw/temp table.

You should be able to find plenty of DAO code examples to help you from here.

The only disadvantages of this approach is that it would tend to be slower than a purely in-memory approach, and the .ACCDB file would tend to bloat up unnecessarily and require regular compacting.

Should you want to use the in-memory approach (which might be prone to out-of-memory errors with that much data), you would need to read your data line-by-line (look for help on VBA's Open & Line Input#) into an array of a custom class with a custom default member (this is obscure & tricky: details [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx)) which is a sort-key that concatenates all the fields you want to sort on.  Then sort it (MedianThreeQuickSort1 from [here](http://www.bvbcode.com/code/fxqdalbp-281461) is the best & quickest VBA sorting code I have found), and step through the array more or less as I suggested with the DAO code.

This would involve only one loop through your data, and possibly less memory usage than two unsorted loops of the dataset.